# Expected length of the "greedy" increasing sub-sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, random

Given a sequence of random unique integers of length $n$, if I select every element that is the largest so far how how many elements should I expect to select?

This seems superficially similar to [this problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) but based on some trivial counter examples ($9,8,7,6,5,...$) has different results.

Comment: This is a much simpler problem.  The probability that the $k$th element is larger than all previous ones is $1/k$.  Now sum the expectations.

Comment: Put that in as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From symmetry considerations, it's easy to see that the $k$th element has exactly a $1/k$ chance of being the largest among the first $k$ terms.  By linearity of expectation, the expected number of "record-breakers" in a random ordering is just $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k$.  This is the $n$th harmonic number, which is well-approximated by $\ln n + \gamma$, where $\gamma = 0.5772\ldots$ is Euler's constant.

Comment: i.e for reasonably lengthened sequence "a small positive integer". (Which as it happens, for my purposes, is accurate enough.)

Comment: @BCS This problem also has a famous interpretation in terms of the expected number of clumps of traffic on a long stretch of single-lane highway (each car that is slower than all the ones in front of it separates from the pack).

Comment: This result contains a lesson about the penalty for greed. The greedy increasing subsequence and the greedy decreasing subsequence have lengths approximately $\ln n$, but if you take the longest possible increasing sequence and the longest possible decreasing subsequence, at least one of them will have length approximately $\sqrt n$ or more, which is (for large $n$) way larger than $\ln n$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass +1 Nice observation.  I found this paper which derives the limiting distribution for the longest increasing subsequence of a *random* permutation, and cites earlier work that the average length is $\sim 2\sqrt{n}$, comparable to the lower bound provided by the Erdős-Szekeres argument: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9810105